# Is it possible to set a default value in an AngularJS expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-interpolate

I have an AngularJS expression enwrapped in a `<a>` tag. The expression is evaluating an `allow` variable.

```
<a href="#" >{{allow}}</a>
```

In case `allow` is `null` or `undefined` Angular shows nothing. Instead I would like to display a default string.

---

To give you a better understanding, this is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

The modal on the right is generated from the form on the left. If the user didn't enter any text for "Allow Button Text" and "Disallow Button Text" I want to display `ALLOW` and `DON'T ALLOW` respectively.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="test2" class="row"  ng-app="">    
  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" ng-model="title" placeholder="https:/your website.com/wants to:">

  <label for="title">Allow Button Text</label>
  <input type="text"  ng-model="allow" placeholder="ALLOW">

  <label for="title">Disallow Button Text</label>
  <input type="text"  ng-model="disallow" placeholder="DONT ALLOW">     

  <p>{{title}}</p>
  <a href="" >{{disallow}}</a>
  <a href="" >{{allow}}</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "placeholder" in this context? Show an example of what you mean.

Answer (score 12):

If by placeholder you mean default value until `allow` is specified, then it's quite easy:

```
<a href="#">{{ allow || 'Click me' }}</a>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{{allow || 'Click me'}}`? The single pipe `|` introduces a filter in Angular.

Comment: thnks @Gpx, this is what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my friend, But placeholder attribute is not for anchor tag. It is for input fields.

let us know what you exactly want to achieve with this and we can suggest some alternative approach.

As suggested by @dfsq, if you mean placeholder text as the text to show when `allow` is not defined then you can put default text like this:

```
{{allow | 'placeholder text'}}
```